# updating a column from the result of a different query

Tags: mysql

i have tow tables (vehicles and costs) and i have introduced a department column in costs table
so i want to update the department column in the costs table with department from vehicle table

my vehicle table is like this:

```
vehicle Department
S526    424
D097    402
D113    403
D111    430
C005    400
C003    403
C002    403
```

and the costs tavle is like this:

```
car     Dept
D097    
C005    
D113    
D113    
D111    
C005    
D113    
C005    
C003    
C002    
C005    
S526    
C002    
C002
```

How do i update the costs table to have the relevant department

i have tried this but its not working:

```
update costs as h,
(
  select v.vid as 'car',
  v.department as 'department',
  h.VID as 'newcar'
  from vehicles AS v
  join costs as h on v.vid = h.VID and v.costcentre = h.CostCenter
) as t2
set h.department = t2.department
```

Comment: why don't just inner join them? SELECT * FROM vehicle v INNER JOIN cost c ON c.car=v.id;

Comment: show me how please coz its updating all the vehicles with the same department

Comment: since that data can be traced back with inner join from my previous comment, I don't think inserting them there would be a good idea. It would just create redundant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update costs h,vehicles v
set h.Dept = v.Department
where v.vehicle = h.car;
```